# How can I get out numbers from a line which contains strings and numbers in shell?

Tags: shell, split

So I have got a file which contains lines like this :

```
Kiss Bea 3 4 5 4
Nagy Katalin 4 5 2 3
```

I ve tried this:

```
  read name  
        while read var1 var2 var3
        do
            if [ $name == $var1 ]
            then 
                echo $var3
            fi
        done < test.txt
```

`name="Kiss"` 
so `var3= 3 4 5 4` here

My problem is that I can't put thoose numbers (which are in var3) into different variables because I need a script that writes out the average of those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way like this in bash:

```
read name
while read var1 var2 var3
do
    if [ $name == $var1 ]
    then
        echo "scale=2;(${var3// /+})/4" | bc
    fi
done < test.txt
```

Replaced all the spaces with '+' in var3 and the average was done using the bc command.